# jquery-textcomplete not working

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use jquery-textcomplete. But it is not working at all. Check the below code and please help me:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: #fff;
            }
        </style>
        <script>

            $('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
                    words: ['anu', 'annamma', 'googlee', 'suresh namal', 'facebook', 'github', 'microsoft', 'yahoo', 'stackoverflow'],
                    match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
                    search: function (term, callback) {
                        console.log("inside search");
                        callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
                            return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
                        }));
                    },
                    index: 2,
                    replace: function (word) {
                        return word + ' ';
                    }
                }]);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form>
                <textarea id="textcomplete"></textarea>
            </form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anuannemariya/qys16w3d/3/.

Answer (score 0):

**It works well!**

You should input at least 2 characters because of the regular expression `/(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/`.

If you want to input 1 character you can change the regular expression like this:
`/(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{1,}|\w{1,})$/`

Comment: jquery-textcomplete dependencies: jQuery (>= 1.7.0) OR Zepto (>= 1.0)

Comment: @AnuAbraham  put the javascript code at the bottom `</body> <script>...</script></html>`